# User trying to purchase in-app purchase but Apple keeps asking for his password?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, apple-id

I have in-app purchase working in my app. I get many purchases every day (which is great!).  However I had a user contact me today saying that he is trying to make a purchase. He taps to make the purchase and Apple asks for his Apple ID password - which makes sense. However when he enters his password, it simply asks for it again. Any idea why this might be happening or how to resolve it? I don't think it's a coding issue because in-app purchase both works in the sandbox and also for many users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that means he is entering his password incorrectly. That's the only reason Apple would ask multiple times.